# Overlay pmf of true Poisson distribution over histogram of randomly generated samples

Tags: r, poisson

I'm new to both statistics and R. I've generated 100 random samples from a Poisson distribution with lambda = 2.5 using:

```
 samples <- rpois(100,2.5)
```

I've successfully created a relative frequency histogram of the samples:

```
 hist(samples, prob=TRUE)
```

Now I need to overlay the pmf of the true Poisson distribution over the histogram but don't know how to generate the true function. I think this is probably very simple but just can't figure out what to do. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `plot(table(samples)/length(samples)); points(0:8, dpois(0:8,lambda=2.5))` (I hope this isn't homework ...)

Comment: ... but you can be sure it's a repeat question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605191/adding-a-best-fit-normal-on-top-of-a-histogram-in-r/7605889#7605889

Comment: Sorry, it is for homework. Didn't know I shouldn't ask these kinds of questions here. Thanks though. I searched through R help, googled it, and looked on here (though obviously not well enough). Will try to be more thorough next time.

Comment: homework **is** allowed on SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions, but I personally don't like answering those questions.

Comment: I would say it's not quite a dupe, because there are a few considerations that are specifically relevant to plotting discrete distributions (i.e., `hist()` and `curve()` are sub-optimal; they can be tweaked to work OK, but `plot(table(...))` and `points()` work better)

Comment: See also http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e12/help/10/10/1870.html

Answer (score -1):

Get the distribution by plugging values from the domain into the Poisson probability mass function.
The domain is 0-infinity.
The pmf is [e^(-lamda)*lamda^k]/k_factorial
See the wikipedia page for details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution