# Plot histogram and density function curve on one chart

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have a density function f, and I do MCMC sampling for it. To evaluate the goodness of the sampling, I need to plot the `hist` and `curve` within the same chart. The problem of

```
hist(samples);
curve(dfun,add=TRUE);
```

is that they are on the different scale: the frequency of a certain bin is usually hundreds, while the maximum of a density function is about 1 or so. What I want to do is to configure two plots at the same height, with one y-axis on the left and the other on the right. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `prob=TRUE` argument to `hist`:

```
hist(samples, prob=TRUE)
curve(dfun,add=TRUE)
```

Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539/fitting-a-density-curve-to-a-histogram-in-r)

Comment: Thank you, @Dirk Eddelbuettel, it is perfect. One more question. What if my density function is not normalized? The option `prob` does not help. (Besides manually normalization)