# histogram and pdf in the same graph

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fitting a density curve to a histogram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539/fitting-a-density-curve-to-a-histogram-in-r)

I'd like to plot on the same graph the histogram and various pdf's. I've tried for just one pdf with the following code (adopted from code I've found in the web):

```
hist(data, freq = FALSE, col = "grey", breaks = "FD")
.x <- seq(0, 0.1, length.out=100)
curve(dnorm(.x, mean=a, sd=b), col = 2, add = TRUE)
```

It gives me an error. Can you advise me?
For multiple pdf's what's the trick?
And I've observed that the histogram seems to be plot the density (on y-y axis) instead of the number of observations.... how can I change this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your question / problem? We would find it easier to answer.

Comment: Also, whenever one says "it gives me an error" it's a good idea to post what the error is.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539/fitting-a-density-curve-to-a-histogram-in-r

Comment: Suggest searching SO [r] postings with search term 'layout' if you want multiple plots on a page, or with terms "multiple pdfs" if that is your interest. In any case, please take more care in searching and writing questions before submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
h<-hist(data, breaks="FD", col="red", xlab="xTitle", main="Normal pdf and     histogram")
xfit<-seq(min(data),max(data),length=100)
x.norm<-rnorm(n=100000, mean=a, sd=b)
yfit<-dnorm(xfit,mean=mean(x.norm),sd=sd(x.norm))
yfit <- yfit*diff(h$mids[1:2])*length(loose_All)
lines(xfit, yfit, col="blue", lwd=2)
```

Comment: First question and last one are answered! What about if I want to add multiple pdfs in the same plot? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It plots the density instead of the frequency because you specified `freq=FALSE`.  It is not very fair to complain about it doing exactly what you told it to do.

The `curve` function expects an expression involving `x` (not .x) and it does not require you to precompute the x values.  You probably want something like:

```
a <- 5
b <- 2
hist( rnorm(100, a, b), freq=FALSE )
curve( dnorm(x,a,b), add=TRUE )
```

To head of your next question, if you specify `freq=TRUE` (or just leave it out for the default) and add the curve then the curve just runs along the bottom (that is the whole purpose of plotting the histogram as a density rather than frequencies).  You can work around this by scaling the expression given to `curve` by the width of the bins and the number of total points:

```
out <- hist( rnorm(100, a, b) )
curve( dnorm(x,a,b)*100*diff(out$breaks[1:2]), add=TRUE )
```

Though personally the first option (density scale) without tickmark labels on the y-axis makes more sense to me.