# Combining frequency histograms with density lines

Tags: r, histogram, frequency

I have this code:

`MyData <- read.csv2(
    file="C:/Users/Sysop/Desktop/R_Skaiciavimai/Sezonai.csv",header=T,sep=";")
    MyData

```
Data_1<-MyData$Sul11P
Data_2<-MyData$Sul11V
Data_3<-MyData$Sul11R
Data_4<-MyData$Sul11Z

D_adjust<-1

Data_1_density<- density(Data_1,adjust = D_adjust,na.rm = TRUE)
Data_2_density<- density(Data_2,adjust = D_adjust,na.rm = TRUE)
Data_3_density<- density(Data_3,adjust = D_adjust,na.rm = TRUE)
Data_4_density<- density(Data_4,adjust = D_adjust,na.rm = TRUE)

Meginio_Vieta<-'Šulinėlis T1-1'
DataBins<-seq(0, 12, by=0.5)

Col_1 <- rgb(1,0,0,0.4)
Col_2 <- rgb(0,0,1,0.4)
Col_3 <- rgb(0,1,0,0.4)


par( mfrow = c( 2, 2 ) )

myhist <- hist(Data_1,breaks=DataBins, plot=FALSE)
multiplier <- myhist$counts / myhist$density
mydensity <- Data_1_density
mydensity$y <- mydensity$y * multiplier[1]
plot(myhist,xlim =c(0,11),col=Col_2,xlab = expression(NH[4]*-N~ "koncentracija     mg/l"),main = Meginio_Vieta, panel.first = grid(nx = 10, ny = 10))
axis(1, at=c(1,3,5,7,9,11))
mtext("Pavasario sezonas",cex = 0.8,adj=0.5, padj=0)
lines(mydensity,col="red", lwd=2)

myhist <- hist(Data_2,breaks=DataBins, plot=FALSE)
multiplier <- myhist$counts / myhist$density
mydensity <- Data_2_density
mydensity$y <- mydensity$y * multiplier[1]
plot(myhist,xlim =c(0,11),col=Col_2,xlab = expression(NH[4]*-N~ "koncentracija mg/l"),main = Meginio_Vieta, panel.first = grid(nx = 10, ny = 10))
axis(1, at=c(1,3,5,7,9,11))
mtext("Vasaros sezonas",cex = 0.8,adj=0.5, padj=0)
lines(mydensity,col="red", lwd=2)

myhist <- hist(Data_3,breaks=DataBins, plot=FALSE)
multiplier <- myhist$counts / myhist$density
mydensity <- Data_3_density
mydensity$y <- mydensity$y * multiplier[1]
plot(myhist,xlim =c(0,11),col=Col_2,xlab = expression(NH[4]*-N~ "koncentracija mg/l"),main = Meginio_Vieta, panel.first = grid(nx = 10, ny = 10))
axis(1, at=c(1,3,5,7,9,11))
mtext("Rudens sezonas",cex = 0.8,adj=0.5, padj=0)
lines(mydensity,col="red", lwd=2)

myhist <- hist(Data_4,breaks=DataBins, plot=FALSE)
multiplier <- myhist$counts / myhist$density
mydensity <- Data_4_density
mydensity$y <- mydensity$y * multiplier[1]
plot(myhist,xlim =c(0,11),col=Col_2,xlab = expression(NH[4]*-N~ "koncentracijamg/l"),main = Meginio_Vieta, panel.first = grid(nx = 10, ny = 10))
axis(1, at=c(1,3,5,7,9,11))
mtext("Žiemos sezonas",cex = 0.8,adj=0.5, padj=0)
lines(mydensity,col="red", lwd=2)
```

`

Data:

Sul11P  Sul11V  Sul11R  Sul11Z

2,7699  1,4872  0,0725  1,2158

4,9356  3,6808  1,1823  9,5106

0,6507  0,5205  1,3292

1,2734  1,7568  0,1431

1,7568  1,2251  0,541   4,3036

0,3183  1,0875  1,2158  4,0489

1,5058  1,3571  1,4593  0,0279

0,158   0,8682  0,4982  1,0132

9,3601  0,2733  0,9983  1,2511

3,0971  0,5707  1,2232  0,593

4,4951  0,0409  1,1247  0,2175

4,311   0,1208  2,11    3,9392

5,7146  0,0502  1,5307  5,9153

4,3408  1,9105  1,3534  2,4105

1,279   2,3093  1,9105  1,3133

4,2088  1,1108  0,6023  1,2585

2,6863  2,3662  2,2185  1,1952

1,6099  4,5 1,0791  2,1151

1,3998  2,3916  1,4188  1,8873

1,292   3,0035  0,202   1,9337

1,314   2,7165  0,9568

1,56    0,3997  1,0116

```
1,3049  2,2101  

1,7164  0,2647  

    3,225
```

It seems to plot well, result:
http://i60.tinypic.com/2ewzh2u.jpg

But when I try to plot this data:

`Sul13P Sul13V  Sul13R  Sul13Z
6,0046  6,5995  0,5242  8,5514
6,4228  7,5475  2,307   8,9529
4,1177  6,4136  2,4543

4,7683  7,225   1,8367  1,6025
4,6289  2,3247  1,6303  2,4985
0,1573  2,8647  1,4946  1,2195
4,8985  3,8333  2,268   3,2923
5,6235  4,034   0,5763  3,1789
10,8008 4,6345  2,5171  1,833
4,5062  4,8334  2,1304  1,8348
3,7998  3,7775  1,1805  0,4294
2,6175  2,8108  1,6824  3,7217
2,861   2,0003  5,5207  3,5823
4,8037  2,8262  4,1555  2,0624
2,6007  4,548   5,7021  2,4506
4,7572  1,0179  3,4402  1,8176
4,0582  4,8054  5,6494  1,5855
2,5487  3   6,16    2,3472
3,6195  3,3706  6,466   1,518
2,7272  2,9802  4,8413  2,324
2,258   5,9216  3,2208  2,9591
2,6914  5,4954  2,765   2,8241
NA  4,6303  2,5414  1,6298
NA  5,7338  0,4271  2,2164
NA  NA  2,8515  1,5328`

I get this result:http://i61.tinypic.com/1z6quqg.jpg.
For some reason one density curve is not plotted.
This happens with other similar  data sets I have.

Whats is wrong with my code?

Comment: I think because `multiplier[1] == 0`. If `myhist$counts[1]` or `myhist$density[1]` is 0, your multiplier is 0 or inf.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this isue?

Comment: I checked multiplier and it prints lines like this:
7.5 NaN 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 NaN 7.5 NaN NaN NaN N

NaN NaN  12  12  12  12  12 NaN  12  12 NaN NaN  12 NaN NaN 

12.5 12.5 12.5 12.5 12.5 12.5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  

NaN NaN 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN.

When first value is Nan then density curve is not plotted. So maybe is way how to remove these NaN values?

Comment: Exactly, so instead of `multiplier[1]` use `multiplier[!is.na(multiplier)][1]`

Comment: Thank You very much, now it seems to work very well.

I used this solution proposed from here to get multiplier:
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078107/overlay-normal-curve-to-histogram-in-r

which was for data without Na values.