# How to draw a graph for erdos.renyi.game method in R

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I have a random graph in R, I use method `erdos.renyi.game` to generate random graph and I want to generate a line graph for output, my output will be degree distribution of my graph.

my code:

```
library(igraph)
graph <- erdos.renyi.game(n=100, 0.2, type = c("gnp"), directed=FALSE, loops=FALSE)
d <- degree.distribution(graph)
plot(d)
```

but my output is Dot plot.!

Comment: Are you looking for something like `barplot(d)`, or `names(d) <- seq_along(d)-1; barplot(d)`?

Comment: All right, but i want to a normal distribution of random graph.! and i want to a Dot plot for that.

Comment: What is a "normal distribution of random graph"?

Comment: It is a bioinformatics problem. i want to compare of degree distribution and normal distribution with dot plot. ok?

Answer (score 2):

For a line plot you need to use:

```
plot(d,type="l")
```

The default for the `plot()` function is the dotplot.

If all you want is to get a graph of the degree distribution, you can use `hist(degree(graph))`. The function `degree.distribution()` gives you a vector of the relative frequencies of degrees. You can get a histogram showing the distribution of degree values by calling `degree()` and feeding it into `hist()`.

For overlaying a normal curve over your graph, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078107/overlay-normal-curve-to-histogram-in-r).

Comment: Yes, but i want to a normal distribution of random graph. i have not solution for that.

Comment: Have you tried `hist(degree(graph))`? `degree.distribution()` gives you a vector of the relative frequencies of degrees. You can get a histogram showing the distribution of degree values by calling `degree()` and feeding it into `hist()`

Comment: It is good, too.But i have a compare normal distribution with degree distribution of my graph and a Dot plot to it.