# R: Show Frequency of Values and dnorm curve

Tags: r, histogram, frequency, curve

I have imported a csv file with one column and its values.

```
a <- read.csv("/home/file.csv")
```

Now I want a histogram with frequencies of the values

```
h <- hist(as.matrix(a))  

text(h$mids,h$counts,labels=h$counts, adj=c(0.5,-0.5))
```

What does the function `adj=c(0.5,-0.5)` exactly?

```
x <- seq(8,13, 1)   
-> that's the first and end value (8,13)  

curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(a$weight), sd=sd(a$weight)), add=T)
```

Now I have the curve, but not the frequencies of the values anymore.

I also tried it with: `h <- hist(as.matrix(a), prob=T)`

And I can't set the ylab and xlab `h <- hist(as.matrix(a), xlab="..", ylab=".." )` it takes default labs.

Comment: As to *"what does `adj=c(0.5,-0.5)` [do] exactly?"*, have a look at the documentation in `?text` that explains the `adj` argument. Then try experimenting with a few different values for `adj`. If you're still confused, ask a separate question.

Comment: As to the rest of the question, [is this what you're trying to do? *Overlay normal curve to histogram in R.*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20078107/903061)

Comment: Sounds like you might want to fit a model (e.g. linear) first