# Adding a normal distribution to a bar chart in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, normal-distribution

I want to plot a histogram and then overlay that with a normal distribution that represents the distribution of the data. However, my data is already counted:

```
df<- structure(list(trips = c(12955L, 36890L, 47035L, 48650L, 70910L, 
93755L, 45315L, 16565L, 4725L, 9460L), dist.km = c(0.5, 2, 4, 
8.5, 12.5, 17.5, 22.5, 27.5, 32.5, 42.5), share = c(0.03, 0.09, 
0.12, 0.13, 0.18, 0.24, 0.12, 0.04, 0.01, 0.02)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Since the data is already counted, I can use `barplot` instead of `hist`:

```
barplot(df$share, 
          names.arg=census.car$dist.km,
          col="orange", 
          xlab="km", 
          ylab="trips")
```

[image]

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to plot the histogram directly instead of using `barplot` in this case?
2. How can I overlay this bar plot with a normal distribution line that fits my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: if you do not have the original data, then you cannot use `hist`.

Q2: with some work.

First, `barplot` does not provide a discrete x-axis. Looking at your plot, this is clearly shown where the spacing between the first two columns (2-0.5 = 1.5) is the same as the last two columns (42.5-32.5 = 10). You can get the x-axis mid-points by looking at the (invisible) return value of `barplot`:

```
(barplot(df$share, names.arg=df$dist.km,
         col="orange", xlab="km", ylab="trips"))
#       [,1]
#  [1,]  0.7
#  [2,]  1.9
#  [3,]  3.1
#  [4,]  4.3
#  [5,]  5.5
#  [6,]  6.7
#  [7,]  7.9
#  [8,]  9.1
#  [9,] 10.3
# [10,] 11.5
```

The points are equi-distant despite the actual points not doing that. This equi-distance is because R is effectively assuming categorical data, not continuous.

To compensate for that, we can either adjust the width of the plots or the space between them. If we changed the width, then we would be conflating width with visual importance, something we should avoid, so let's go with "space":

```
(bp <- barplot(df$share, names.arg=df$dist.km,
               space = c(0, diff(df$dist.km)),
               col="orange", xlab="km", ylab="trips"))
#       [,1]
#  [1,]  0.5
#  [2,]  3.0
#  [3,]  6.0
#  [4,] 11.5
#  [5,] 16.5
#  [6,] 22.5
#  [7,] 28.5
#  [8,] 34.5
#  [9,] 40.5
# [10,] 51.5
```

[image: barplot adjusted for non-equi-distant spacing]

In order to plot a normal curve, we need the original distribution's mean and standard deviation. Without the original data, we can approximate it with weighted mean and weighted standard deviation, both provided by the `Hmisc` package.

```
mu <- Hmisc::wtd.mean(df$dist.km, df$trips)
sigma <- sqrt(Hmisc::wtd.var(df$dist.km, weights = df$trips))
c(mu, sigma)
# [1] 13.565338  8.911899
```

Unfortunately, as we see in the output from the second `barplot` above, the x-axis is not on the same scale as the data. Luckily, it's still continuous and linear for us, so we just need to adjust for that. We can calculate it manually, but for the sake of argument, here's a back-transformation function:

```
func <- function(a) {
  (min(df$dist.km) - bp[1,1]) + # the offset, happens to be 0 here since
                                # the first datapoint is exactly 0.5
    a * diff(range(bp[,1])) / diff(range(df$dist.km))
}

mu2 <- func(mu)
sigma2 <- sigma
c(mu2, sigma2)
# [1] 16.472196  8.911899
```

Notice that we do not adjust the deviation: recall (from your statistics class) that when you add a value to all data in the source, the "location" stats (e.g., mean, median) are adjusted similarly (add the value) but the variance is unchanged.

So we can now use `curve` to add that to the plot:

```
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mu2, sd=sigma2),
      col = "red", lwd = 2, add=TRUE)
```

[image: barplot with un-scaled normal curve]

Note: The function call we gave as the first argument to `curve` needs the `x` variable there, even though we haven't defined it. This is used internally to `curve` and replaced with the actual vector of values. It can be different, perhaps with `curve(dnorm(yy,...), xname="yy")`.

Aesthetically it is not high enough ... we can scale it with the max frequency:

```
# start over
bp <- barplot(df$share, names.arg=df$dist.km,
              space = c(0, diff(df$dist.km)),
              col="orange", xlab="km", ylab="trips")
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mu2, sd=sigma2) / max(df$share),
      col = "red", lwd = 2, add=TRUE)
```

[image: barplot with adjusted normal curve]

Last point: this normal curve is an approximation, and though it is good it is still imperfect. If you have the original data, it would be much better to use `hist` and actual mu/sigma values.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a great link to solve yor question:

[Overlay normal curve to histogram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078107/overlay-normal-curve-to-histogram-in-r)

Answering your questions:

1- Yes, you should make dist.km and trips as 1 variable and then call the function hist(), but with your data format your way is pretty cool.

2- Using curve() and lines() as the link says.

Comment: The link that you sent is when I have the histogram, I am looking for a way to plot the normal distribution on the bar chart, or plot the histogram (in way other than changing my data to a huge dataset) and then plot the normal distribution.