# Probability distribution of throwing 100 dice using Gaussian/Normal distribution bell curve

Tags: r, statistics, probability, probability-distribution

I have a program that simulates a fair dice 100 times. 
Using this program I need to have a bell curve over the histogram showing normal/Gaussian distribution. 
In my code The variable representing the outcome of the experiment is z.
The definition of the bell curve contains two parameters: ave determines where on the z-axis the curve must have a maximum and sig determines the width of the peak.

```
 set.seed(123)

 x <- sample(1:6, size=100, replace = TRUE)

 hist(x,
 main="100 fair rolls",
 xlab = "Dice Result",
 ylab = "Probability",
 xlim=c(0.5,6.5), 
 breaks=-1:100+.5,
 prob=TRUE )
```

Gaussian distribution equation I have so far:

```
    bell<-function(z,ave,sig){
exp(-(z-ave)^2/(2*sig))/sqrt(2*pi*sig)
    }

    points<-0:600

    lines(points,bell(points,350,292))
```

Comment: There is a built-in function, `dnorm`, which does what you want `bell` to do.

Comment: Have you seen [Overlay normal curve to histogram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20078107/4752675) ?

Comment: @G5W  I have but I need to use the equation: exp(-(z-ave)^2/(2*sig))/sqrt(2*pi*sig) and not just use the dnorm function

Comment: @JaredJoss `dnorm` uses the same formula which you are using. If you want to see what logic the code of dnorm uses, please find it here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/dnorm.c

Comment: Could you please show me how to do it? I am new to R