# Constructing a histogram of exceedances and overlying Generalised Pareto pdf in R

Tags: r, pdf, histogram

My question concerns Fig 8 of [this publication,](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221926990_Modeling_Extreme_Climate_Events_Two_Case_Studies_in_Mexico) which is reproduced below. Specifically, how was the histogram of exceedances with overlying pdf constructed in R given the set of data, the m.l.e.s for the GP distribution and an approximate threshold? I can't seem to find a tool in R which achieves this. Could someone give an example for a code to reproduce a diagram of this type?
[image]

Comment: This question uses a normal distribution but it should work with any distribution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078107/overlay-normal-curve-to-histogram-in-r