# How would I plot a curve line above all bars in a histogram?

Tags: r, histogram

I have create a histogram;

```
hist(height, ylim = c(0, 50), xlab="height", ylab="count")
```

Am I now trying to plot a curve line above all the bars in a histogram to show wether the bar plots are skewed left or right etc. Is there a way to do this without using density as I want to keep count 0 to 50 along the y-axis.

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078107/overlay-normal-curve-to-histogram-in-r

Comment: @BillChen thanks so much! I found one in that answer that helps!