# R + ggplot2 - plotting normal curve overtop of histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a normal curve over top of some data that has been plotted in a histogram format.  I thought this would be relatively straightforward.  So far I have:

```
x = rnorm(2000, mean=-5, sd=4)

a_hist = ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x), fill='darkred') +
  stat_function(fun=dnorm, args(list(mean=-5, 4)))
```

This gets me everything except the normal curve.  I'm guessing it's because of the axes but when I tried to mess around with the mean/SD/counts it still didn't show.  I also thought it might be because of the aes mappings.  But ggplot wouldn't allow me to put the data into the base `ggplot` call since its a vector and not a dataframe.  Trying to coerce it into a data frame and passing it in as such gave me other errors.  I explored the `stat_function()` parameter `position` but couldn't find any documentation on how to use it other than 'it takes a string'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overlay normal curve to histogram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078107/overlay-normal-curve-to-histogram-in-r)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's in base R.  I tried to mimic a couple of their solutions but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get these overlays. Either you scale histogram to density or you scale density to count scale. Here are two examples:

### Scaling histogram to density

No prior knowledge needed, except from the `dnorm()` arguments.

```
library(ggplot2)

n <- 2000
x = rnorm(n, mean=-5, sd=4)

ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x, y = after_stat(density)), fill='darkred') +
  stat_function(fun=dnorm, args= list(mean=-5, sd = 4))
```

### Scaling density to counts

Need to know the number of observations `n` and set a known `binwidth`.

```
binwidth <- 1
ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x), fill='darkred', binwidth = binwidth) +
  stat_function(fun=dnorm, args= list(mean=-5, sd = 4),
                aes(y = after_stat(y * binwidth * n)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work.  My histogram is now in a more logical density plot but there's still no curve overlayed.  I tried changing the color of the curve and making it geom="points" to see if it was hiding.  No luck.

Comment: What version of ggplot2 are you running? Code above assumes v3.3.0

Comment: Yep. I went and updated everything to make sure.  R, ggplot, and all other packages up to date.