# Adding a normal distribution curve to a histogram

Tags: r, plot, histogram, curve

My code for the Histogram is

```
hist(rnorm(1000), prob=TRUE)
```

this gives me the proper histogram, but i need to plot the normal distribution over it.
here's the code i tried for that:

```
curve(rnorm(x, 1000), -4, 1000, add=TRUE)
```

someone in my class said i needed that range so i threw in a million ideas of what it could be to make the plot (obviously -4,1000 didn't work). An help would be appreciated, I am super confused. it doesn't even throw an error message, R literally doesn't do anything when i run that second code.

Comment: R definitely does something when you run that code

Comment: You probably want to use dnorm instead of rnorm though.

Comment: This seems to be a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078107/overlay-normal-curve-to-histogram-in-r

Comment: `hist(rnorm(1000),prob=TRUE)`
`lines(seq(-3,3,.1), dnorm(seq(-3,3,.1)), col='red')`

Comment: thank you so much! R. Schifini that code worked!

Comment: Obviously no one yet has shown you how to use the genuine R documentation? In R type `help('curve')`  or `?curve`  on how to specify it's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I like the `curve` solution.

```
hist(rnorm(1000), prob=TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x), add=TRUE)
```

[image]