# how to plot histogram and pdf together in r

Tags: r, plot, histogram, probability-density

I want to superimpose the PDF of a fitted model following `gamma(lambda,k)` with a histogram.
I write :

```
hist(pressure)
curve(dgamma(x, lambda, k), add=TRUE, col="red")
```

but I am confused on what the value "x" is.
Anyone help please?

Comment: x is a vector of quantiles. see `?dgamma`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add density lines to histogram and cumulative histogram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960896/add-density-lines-to-histogram-and-cumulative-histogram)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x <- rgamma(100,2,1) #sample
h <- hist(x, plot=FALSE) #generate hist
plot(h, col="grey") #plot hist
xlines <-seq(min(h$breaks),max(h$breaks),length.out=100) #seq of x for pdf
lines(x = xlines,y=dgamma(xlines,2,1) *length(x)*diff(h$breaks)[1])
```

[image: Histogram with PDF]

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a vector of values of the support for which you want to obtain the value of the PDF. You may want to compare

```
plot(dgamma(1:20, shape=1))
```

with the first plot of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution (parameter 1)

Answer (score 0):

`truehist()` is from the MASS package and scales the counts to give an estimate of the probability density.

Use the `lines()` and `density()` functions to overlay a density plot of the weights values on the histogram.

```
library(MASS)

truehist(mtcars$mpg) #mtcars dataset available in base R

lines(density(mtcars$mpg))
```

[image]

- UPDATE:
  Onc can draw the same plot using `ggplot()` function in **ggplot2** library.

  library(ggplot2)

  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), binwidth = 1) + geom_density()

Comment: Note that the OP wanted to draw a Gamma PDF (with fitted parameters) over the histogram. Which is not the same as drawing an empirical density fitted with `density` or `geom_density`. Can be seen nicely on your plot, the black line is definitely not a Gamma PDF.