# Histogram with curve in R

Tags: r, histogram, curve

I need a histogram for my data, but could not find one with a curve. Can anyone please suggest a histogram showing frequencies (not densitities) with a curve for the data below? Fancy ones are preferred, but no worries if not :)

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
hist(x)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539/fitting-a-density-curve-to-a-histogram-in-r

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the slow, step-by-step version.

This is your data.

```
population_mean <- 0
population_sd <- 1
n <- 1000
x <- rnorm(n, population_mean, population_sd)
```

These are some `x` coordinates for drawing a curve.  Notice the use of `qnorm` to get lower and upper quantiles from a normal distribution.

```
population_x <- seq(
  qnorm(0.001, population_mean, population_sd), 
  qnorm(0.999, population_mean, population_sd), 
  length.out = 1000
)
```

In order to convert from density to counts, we need to know the binwidth.  This is easiest if we specify it ourselves.

```
binwidth <- 0.5
breaks <- seq(floor(min(x)), ceiling(max(x)), binwidth)
```

Here's our histogram.

```
hist(x, breaks)
```

The count curve is the normal density times the number of data points divided by the binwidth.

```
lines(
  population_x, 
  n * dnorm(population_x, population_mean, population_sd) * binwidth, 
  col = "red"
)
```

Let's see that again with the sample distribution rather than the population distribution.

```
sample_mean <- mean(x)
sample_sd <- sd(x)
sample_x <- seq(
  qnorm(0.001, sample_mean, sample_sd), 
  qnorm(0.999, sample_mean, sample_sd), 
  length.out = 1000
)
lines(
  population_x, 
  n * dnorm(sample_x, sample_mean, sample_sd) * binwidth, 
  col = "blue"
)
```

[image: histogram with frequency curves]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this...?

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(1000)
hist(x, las=1)

par(new=TRUE)   
plot(density(x), col=2, yaxt="n", xaxt="n",
     bty='n', xlab="", ylab="", main='')
axis(4, las=1)
```

[image]

Frequency is depicted in the left *y* axis and Probability (for the density line) is in the right *y* axis.

Comment: They did specify they wanted frequencies in their histogram and not densities.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you would use a density curve.

Try this:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
hist(x)
curve(dnorm, col = 2, add = TRUE)
```

Comment: The histogram look OK, but the curve does not seem to be working I suppose?

Comment: Oh well, you wanted a histogram showing frequencies, not just density, my mistake. Richie Cotton's answer is straight on.