# How to plot exponential function on barplot R?

Tags: r, graph, plot, exponential

So I have a barplot in which the y axis is the log (frequencies). From just eyeing it, it appears that bars decrease exponentially, but I would like to know this for sure. What I want to do is also plot an exponential on this same graph. Thus, if my bars fall below the exponential, I would know that my bars to decrease either exponentially or faster than exponential, and if the bars lie on top of the exponential, I would know that they dont decrease exponentially. How do I plot an exponential on a bar graph?

Here is my graph if that helps:

[image]

Comment: You can find two exponential curves, one above and one below your values.  Thus, your premise is flawed.

Comment: I would think it depends on the command you used to generate this barplot. Did you use the ggplot2 package?

Comment: @vinnief Almost certainly no.

Comment: i just used the barplot() function in R

Comment: This is not an `R` question as much as it is a stats question. You want to fit an exponential curve to your data. That is the challenge. Once you have that, plotting it is straightforward.

Comment: There's already a wealth of information out about fitting distributions to your data. You can start with http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf (see package `MASS:::fitdistr`).

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to fit density of an exponential function, you should probably plot density histogram (not frequency). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539/fitting-a-density-curve-to-a-histogram-in-r) on how to plot distributions in R.

This is how I would do it.

```
x.gen <- rexp(1000, rate = 3)
hist(x.gen, prob = TRUE)

library(MASS)
x.est <- fitdistr(x.gen, "exponential")$estimate

curve(dexp(x, rate = x.est), add = TRUE, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way of visually inspecting if two distributions are the same is with a Quantile-Quantile plot, or Q-Q plot for short.  Typically this is done when inspecting if a distribution follows standard normal.

The basic idea is to plot your data, against some theoretical quantiles, and if it matches that distribution, you will see a straight line. For example:

```
x <- qnorm(seq(0,1,l=1002))  # Theoretical normal quantiles
x <- x[-c(1, length(x))]  # Drop ends because they are -Inf and Inf
y <- rnorm(1000)  # Actual data. 1000 points drawn from a normal distribution
l.1 <- lm(sort(y)~sort(x))
qqplot(x, y, xlab="Theoretical Quantiles", ylab="Actual Quantiles")
abline(coef(l.1)[1], coef(l.1)[2])
```

[image: Q-Q Plot for normal distribution]

Under perfect conditions you should see a straight line when plotting the theoretical quantiles against your data. So you can do the same plotting your data against the exponential function you think it will follow.