# Fit generic function (special case Power Law) to a histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram, curve-fitting

How can I fit a generic curve to an histogram in R?

For instance, in the example: [Fitting a density curve to a histogram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539/fitting-a-density-curve-to-a-histogram-in-r) it's shown how to use ggplot density estimate, but I want to fit any kind of curve (to be more specific in this case I want to fit a power law, but it could be any other one, like x^2).

How do I fit that to the data:

```
hdat <- hist(c(rep(65, times=5), rep(25, times=5), rep(35, times=10), rep(45, times=4)))
```

Comment: Have a look at `poly`, `nls` and `loess`.

Comment: @DWin Thank you, but that doesn't explain how to fit an histogram, it shows how to fit a 2D data sample.

Comment: A histogram is a 2D data sample

Comment: `y <- hdat$counts;  x <- hdat$mids`