# Because it curve does not work with histogram?

Tags: r, histogram

I have no idea why this simple command does not work?

```
    set.seed(12345)
    x<-rnorm(1000,0,10)
    hist(x)
    curve(dnorm(x,0, 10), add=TRUE, yaxt="n", col="red", log=FALSE)
```

Comment: Possible dupe: [Fitting a density curve to a histogram in R](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1497539/903061).

Comment: So many duplicates, so little time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overlaying density over a frequency graph. You need to convert your histogram to a density plot.

```
hist(x, freq = FALSE)
curve(dnorm(x,0, 10), add=TRUE, col="red", log=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: The answer is correct. Edit the code, however, by the image.