# Graph density curve from output from boot library package

Tags: r, bootstrap-4, histogram, density-plot

i want to be able show density curve of the results of the bootstrap sample done in the package boot.

The package allows plot() to be used to graph histogram

But i cannot work out how to add density curve to plot ()
or which function will allow me to do density curve

```
library(boot)
library(ISLR2)

alpha.fn = function(data,index)
{
  X = data$X[index]
  Y = data$Y[index]
    (var(Y) - cov(X, Y)) / ( var(X) + var(Y) - 2 * cov(X, Y))
}

bootsample = boot(data, alpha.fn, R= 500)
plot(bootsample, index= 1)
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: Can you edit your question to make this a reproducible example?

Comment: have updated with more detail

Comment: It's a duplicate a few times over.  Here is another answer I have on this a while back:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539/fitting-a-density-curve-to-a-histogram-in-r

Comment: i cant see where they use the output of library boot()